# Delete all lines that contain duplicate letters

Tags: linux, command-line, sed, terminal

I've tried to find the existing topics about this theme and I found something but it's not the 100% what I'm looking for and my internet connection is bad last few days so I needed to quit searching and post a new thread...

So my problem is I have a .txt file with many lines (over 50000), every line has 5 letter string like this:

```
KKIUB
SDCVG
KJUTT
NGTHH
WWLEE
XGHTP
NJFRT
PPSFF
ZZZLP
XDRFX
JJJJJ
KIEYW
...
```

I want all lines in a file that contain two (or more) same letters to be deleted. The order of duplicates isn't important, so all lines that contain a letter two times in a line must be deleted. Please note that sometimes there can be all 5 same letters, sometimes 3 same letters, sometimes only 2 same letters + not close to each other, e.g "GOHIG".

```
KKIUB ---> delete
SDCVG ---> stays
KJUTT ---> delete
NGTHH ---> delete
WWLEE ---> delete
XGHTP ---> stays
NJFRT ---> stays
PPSFF ---> delete
ZZZLP ---> delete
XDRFX ---> delete
JJJJJ ---> delete
KIEYW ---> stays
```

I'm trying with `sed` function but was not able to have good results. Also I would like to export it into another .txt file. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed -e '/\(.\).*\1/d' yourfile > youroutputfile
```

Comment: thank you, it works. Is possible to make output in another file?

Comment: done ,  you may want to try that.

Comment: Or just `grep -v '\(.\).*\1'`

Comment: You need to change nothing.

Comment: @Vcore9: "Is possible to make output in another file?" Yes, then it will be `sed -e '/\(.\).*\1/d' yourfile > another`  (sorry, you asked for it ;-)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas any idea why `PCRE` does lot better than BRE/ERE? I used OP's sample pasted 240000 times and `grep -vP '(.).*\1'` is more than 3 times faster..

Answer (score 0):

You can use grep

```
grep -vE "(.).*\1" input.txt > output.txt
```

For example

```
% cat input.txt 
KKIUB
SDCVG
KJUTT
NGTHH
WWLEE
XGHTP
NJFRT
PPSFF
ZZZLP
XDRFX
JJJJJ
KIEYW

% grep -vE "(.).*\1" input.txt > output.txt

% cat output.txt 
SDCVG
XGHTP
NJFRT
KIEYW
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. This question was answered and the answer was accepted 6 years ago. If your answer adds something new, please specify what that is.

Comment: @GraceThompson, it should be obvious that it adds the usage of `grep` that is a slightly more appropriate tool here (as more specialised than `sed`), though in this instance, it's not portable as there's no back-reference in POSIX EREs (contrary to BREs). `grep -v '\(.\).*\1'` would have been more portable (as I actually pointed out in a comment to the accepted answer some 6 years ago).

Comment: @GraceThompson, I just thought Stéphane Chazelas
  comment above was so good that it deserved to be an answer in itself.